# Do these Silverlight 4 themes work with Silverlight 5?

Tags: silverlight

I just installed Silverlight 5 and tried using these themes: 
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14590

And they do not seem to work.  I just get a blank screen when I try to use them.  But this is my first Silverlight project, so perhaps I'm doing something wrong.  Also, this is a simple web upload utility, and SL4 seems to have more info on it, so would Silverlight 4 be just as good to use as SL5?

My App.xaml looks like this:

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             x:Class="FileUpload.App"
             >
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Styles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/CoreStyles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/SDKStyles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/ToolkitStyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: I had a quick play and got the JetPack theme to work in SL5.  The only error I encountered along the way was because I forgot to unblock the JetPack.vsix file.  Normally, when you get a blank white screen in Silverlight, it's because there was an uncaught exception.  If so, the SL plugin will write the stacktrace into a JavaScript error.  Does anything turn up in IE's Developer Tools (or the equivalent in your preferred browser)?

Comment: Luke, thanks for letting me know it works, that's really all I needed.  But unfortunately I, personally, can't get it to work, and don't see any error in VS or Javascript.  I added my App.xaml file above in case I did anything wrong.  Do you see any problems in it?  Also, what is JetPack.vsix?  I just have the xaml files above...

Comment: The .vsix files are in SL4Themes-templates.zip, which you can find at the link above.  They are Visual Studio extensions, which you can double-click to install.  Once installed they provide templates for creating new projects.  As for your App.xaml, I'd remove the `~` from the front of all of the `Source`s.  Also, if you're using anything from within `ToolkitStyles.xaml`, add references to all `System.Windows.*.Toolkit` DLLs.

Comment: Also, what's in your MainPage.xaml?

Comment: If it works at designtime (and if it doesn't too) Try putting InitializeComponent() in the App() constructor, this was an issue we struggled with a long time. BTW: Make sure the .Web side of your project is the startupproject when launching in a browser.

Comment: Luke, this project is based on SilverLightFileUpload, but I deleted everything unique to that project from MainPage.xaml, and no luck.  I tried everything suggested.  It works when I start a new project, though, so I think I will do that.

Comment: Dave: did you work out what the problem was?